# Google search - Python

Tags: python, search-engine

I would like to get top ten result from google search engine. I wrote:

```
from google import search
for i in search('python', stop=10):
    print i
```

It returns more than 10 results. What is a proper way to get top n results? When I change stop=10 to stop=2 it returns exact the same number of results. Is it possible to print only main domain names (now it prints multiple links from the same domain (wikipedia for example) and also images if they are in the first result page)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  googlescraper module here .

## How many urls did we get on all pages?

```
print(sum(len(page['results']) for page in results))
```

## How many hits has google found with our keyword (as shown on the first page)?

```
print(results[0]['num_results_for_kw'])
```

You can check out this link for more info:
[Check this link](http://incolumitas.com/2013/01/06/googlesearch-a-rapid-python-class-to-get-search-results/)

Hope it help ;)

Comment: I read about it but it is a module for python 3.4 and newer. I use 2.7...

Answer (score 1):

From reading [the source code for `search`](http://pythonhosted.org/google/google-pysrc.html#search), it looks like the real behavior is that it returns pages full of results until it reaches (or passes) `stop`. So if there are 14 links on the first page of results, you'll get at least 14 links.

But it's pretty easy to enumerate less than that. Here's code that should do the trick:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import islice

from google import search

for url in islice(search('python', stop=5), 0, 5):
    print(url)
```